# How to make S3 read svg file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, svg

I have a public bucket on `s3` that contains files(SVG, png, jpg) all files working fine except SVG one when I open it I got this thing:

[image]

I add metadata for the SVG file but again same error:

[image]

Comment: Based on the first line of that error message your file does not appear to be an SVG file.

Comment: Did you upload a Java source file instead?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1):

The `XML Parsing error: syntax error` is a generic browser error saying that your XML file is not well formed according to the XML specification.

Read more about this error here: [XML Parsing error: syntax error](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/SAXError.html)

In this case your SVG file is invalid, and you need to upload a valid one.

When you upload a SVG file via console you do not need to add the metadata as the S3 service will get by the file metadata and you be able to read this file on the browser without problems.